# Which object detection model suitable for raspberry pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi, object-detection, raspberry-pi4

I want to make object detection application with raspberry pi 4 4gb Ram.The problem is that I dont be sure which object detection model I should use. I mean which one is suitable for raspberry pi 4. Besides , I dont have a USB accelerator stick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobilenet v1 is quite fast on pi 4, look at the below blogpost for more details - 
https://www.hackster.io/news/benchmarking-tensorflow-lite-on-the-new-raspberry-pi-4-model-b-3fd859d05b98